# JSF RenderKitUtils throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at rendering page

Tags: jsf

My application is throwing the following exception in stdout but I still wasn't able to reproduce the steps that cause this problem. I suspect this has to do with redirecting, because I use Single Page Application principle, and that page that is shown in exception is accessible only by a redirect. It is strange that the exception is throw more or less 20 times successively in the same second, besides it is totally random at the day. It is possible that some component can cause this? I am totally lost in what I should debug to fix this problem.

I am using Tomcat 7.0.37 and Mojarra 2.2.8.

```
Jul 23, 2018 2:58:12 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/public/erroInterno.xhtml]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.buildTypeArrayFromString(RenderKitUtils.java:913)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.determineContentType(RenderKitUtils.java:563)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:260)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1177)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at br.com.igate.smartcompras.sistema.util.MyViewHandler.renderView(MyViewHandler.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:203)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

---

After debugging step by step, I found that *RenderKitUtils.buildTypeArrayFromString* is called after a redirect and the part of code that is throwing this exception is responsible for treating "Content Type" request parameter. For some reason it looks like Content Type its coming empty from the request.

Comment: Start with br.com.igate.smartcompras.sistema.util.MyViewHandler.renderView(MyViewHandler.java:75)... what does it do?

Comment: It visits the tree view and when it founds a commandbutton or commandlink adds a js function to "onerror" that redirects to our error page. It concats the existing onerror value with _;redirectToErrorPage(error);_ js function

Comment: Sorry, it was sort of a rethorical question in that you should investigate if it plays a role in getting this error since the error you get is not common and what you do is very specific.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. I started from the class you suggested. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related to a bug in Mojarra, detected even in 2.2.12 version, as described in "affected versions" in issue description:

https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4081

Some user-agent may send the Accept Encoding as just a '/', which causes "typeSubTypeParts" becoming empty, and accessing typeSubTypeParts[0] causes a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Still I haven't found a way to reproduce this problem.

Searching the [sources](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2_3_SWITCH/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/RenderKitUtils.java#L1005) I found that this bug is fixed in version 2.3 of Mojarra, but none of 2.2.X versions (currently 2.2.14).

---

**SOLUTION UPDATE**: I was in doubt about what was triggering this bug. Looking at the access logs of Tomcat, I found that there is a IP (probably a BOT) that is sending the same requests at the same time the exceptions have been captured. My suspicious is that it is sending "Accept: /" in the request header, JSF process this header and throws the exception.

Comment: Compliments, great debugging!